# why php win32 on windows7 64 cannot connect to mysql 32 or 64 installed on the same machine?

Tags: php, mysql, windows-7, 32bit-64bit

I've installed Apache 2.2 and PHP 32bit on a Windows 7 64bit. 
I configured properly PHP to run as a module and works like a charm.

Then I've installed MySQL Server 5.1 64bit.
After activating mysql or mysqli, php runs as expected but when I connect to localhost with the browser, the php script cannot connect to the database using mysql_connetc() and it generate a timeout error.

Running phpinfo() it says that the mysql modules are running with no errors.

I've tried to uninistall mysql server win64 and reinstall the same version but for win32.
The same happens.

Comment: If youre trying to connect to `localhost` try using `127.0.0.1` instead.

Comment: As long as i ask the question i googled around and I found an answer on the mysql forum

Comment: If you've found a solution, please post an answer with the details and ideally a link, then accept your own answer

Comment: It says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". I wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling around I found this post on the mysql forum

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,366955,366962#msg-366962
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,366955,378099#msg-378099

Basically if you do not set in the host file that localhost is 127.0.0.1 windows 7 uses IPV6 address by default for localhost resulting in a connection error.

Adding this to the host file solve the problem:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added appropriate firewall exceptions? can you connect to mysql using the command-line tool or similar?

Comment: I can connect with the mysql client with no problem. Also I added firewall exception in the firewall for the mysql port

Comment: ok, next test - can you connect to a mysql on a different server with your current PHP install?